# buffering behaviour of stdout in c

Tags: c, stdio, output-buffering

When I run the first code and press ctrl-c immediately there will be no `45` written out to the file. But when I run the second code, I do get `45`.

I couldn't come to the reason why this behavior happens in the below code? If `stdout` is line buffered shouldn't output come after I enter a character? What am I missing?

**First code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp=stdout;
   fp=fopen("myfile","w");
   fprintf(fp,"%d",45);
   getchar();
  // return 0;

}
```

**Second code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp=stdout;
   fprintf(fp,"%d",45);
   getchar();
  // return 0;

}
```

PS: I'm using GCC and the platform is Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats causing confusion is **getchar()**, seems like when it is called it is flushing **stdout**.

If you replace `getchar()` with something like `sleep(10)` then you 45 won't be printed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp=stdout;
   //fp=fopen("myfile","w");
   fprintf(fp,"%d",45);
   sleep(10);
   //getchar();
  // return 0;

}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. `45` may or may not be printed. Kindly see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think `getchar` has anything to do with the buffering you are observing in the first code. If you dont press any character and wait for a while ( ie stay inside `getchar()` ), you'll most probably see an empty file. This happens irrespective of whether you've stalled the program with `getchar`, `sleep` or a `while(1)`.

Now you press `Ctrl-C` for which your program has no handler registered and hence your program terminates abruptly. ***Whether buffers/streams are flushed on abrupt program termination is implementation defined***. Read the full story here

[Why is data not being flushed to file on process exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281255/why-is-data-not-being-flushed-to-file-on-process-exit)

For example, on my system ( Windows 7, Code Blocks which uses gcc and mingw framework internally ), I can see `45` indeed being flushed into the file irrespective of using `getchar` or anything when I terminate it abruptly. ie on my system, the implementation is flushing data to the file on abrupt program termination.

***So, the bottom line is, what happens when you do things in a non-normal fashion is implementation defined!***

But the second case is indeed a curious one where `getchar` *seems* to be flushing the `stdout` buffer. I shall update on that as soon as I find the exact cause of why `getchar` is/seems-to-be flushing `stdout` buffer

Comment: Thanks for the information.But i wanted to know particularly why it behaves oddly in the second code where stdout is supposed to be line buffered but it was not behaving that way..

Answer (score -4):

The first case you are writing to a physical file. fopen, fclose are buffered I/O depends on the implementation, data may not be committed immediately until the buffer is full. Calling fclose() will cause the buffer to be written to disk.

The second case you are writing to STDIO and data written to STDIO normally show up immediately.

Comment: -1: data written to stdout doesn't usually show up "immediately" but is line-buffered, just as other files are.

Comment: **STDIO normally show up immediately.** that's wrong, stdout is line-buffered.