# About process and sleep()

Tags: c, linux, sleep

I have write a program by C and run it in Ubuntu,the main code is follow:

```
int main(){    
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        printf("d");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("a");
        sleep(4);
    }
}
```

The question is: why the code `sleep(4);` run before `printf("a");`

hope someone can give me a answer,thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. Most probably, `printf()` buffered its output until a chance to output the buffer (in your case, when the process terminated).

Comment: Yes and OP should use either `\n` or `fflush(stdout)`

Answer (score 3):

> Q: why the code sleep(4) run before printf("a")?

A: printf("a") actually runs *BEFORE* "sleep(4)", just like you see in the code.

However, it doesn't *DISPLAY* immediately.

The issue is "buffering".

Look here for more details:

- [buffering behaviour of stdout in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339519/buffering-behaviour-of-stdout-in-c)
- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

SUGGESTED ALTERNATIVE:

```
pid_t pid=fork();
if(pid==0){
    fprintf(stderr, "d");
    exit(0);
}
else{
    fprintf(stderr, "a");
    sleep(4);
}
```

The reason is that "stderr" is unbuffered: you'll see the output immediately.

Alternatives to using stderr include calling `fflush(stdout)` or [modifying the stream](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=setvbuf%283%29).

Answer (score 2):

It's not, but it may appear that way.  `printf` puts its output into a buffer that probably only gets flushed after the `sleep` runs.  Try putting a call to `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`, but before the call to `sleep`.