# is fclose() call needed when writing to file

Tags: c, fwrite

Say I'm writing to a file but I want to end the write by turning off the power to the machine, would that be a problem that the fclose() function didn't get called?

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* print some text */
while(1){
//write something...
}
//Dont want to call this
fclose(f);
```

Comment: I would rather be concerned about problems caused by a write operation interrupted by power down.

Comment: you should `fflush` your handles as soon as you're writing. But even that doesn't guarantee that the disk won't be corrupt if a write occurs while you're powering it off.

Comment: Anyway to communicate to my program that I want to shut off the machine from the outside then?

Comment: you could create a certain file on disk, or send a signal prior to powering off. And that would leave the chance to `fclose` the file :)

Comment: There are nice mechanisms implemented in modern OSs that will gracefully terminate all of the processes before turning the power off.

Comment: That's a joke. Open and close the close the file for every write, if you want to throw a rock at it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. *"by turning off the power to the machine"*. There is a difference between pushing the "off" button and cutting power at the wall.

Comment: hm, would be throwing out of the window considered as powering off?

Comment: @WeatherVane I know. My seond comment was to address the OPs comment.

Comment: @yacc That depends whether the computer is running on battery, or has a very long and firmly attached power cord, and how far the computer travels before coming to rest.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you mean I create a file with a char inside and change it when I want to shut down, and have my program read that char to know when to turn off?

Comment: @EugeneSh. My "joke" remark was to OP. It's a bit like those old cartoons that show someone sitting on a tree branch while sawing it off. "Will I be safe"?

Comment: @bakalolo That is normally handled by signals. So when an operating system is going to shut down it signals all running processes to terminate operation. Signal is called SIGTERM on Unix/Linux.

Comment: Embedded code can be a state machine, and when a brown-out is detected it prevents the code from making any changes that would mean the state is not recoverable on power up.

Comment: @yacc I am confused, so if I shut down the machine normally while the loop is running there is no problemo?

Comment: No problem when you do a graceful shutdown. Unix, Linux handle this with SIGTERM, Windows sends a WM_QUIT message to application.

Comment: and the file is not going to be corrupted?

Comment: Unless you throw your computer out of the window... no. But the process must receive SIGTERM to flush and close everthing. If it's SIGINT (Ctrl-c) or even no signal at all... you see. You should add the OS to the question btw.

Comment: Hey I've just learned that flushing is OS dependant. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281255/why-is-data-not-being-flushed-to-file-on-process-exit. So I think closing will always happen, flushing maybe (mostly yes). Why don't you make a test to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, not as written, if there is any kind of buffering.  And if no buffering, also maybe no.

The buffering mode can be controlled with `setvbuf`.  You can also periodically call `fflush` to flush the buffers.

However, regardless of how you manage the buffering, control is transferred to the OS kernel I/O scheduling, and then to the hardware (which may have its own buffering).

The file I/O routines in `<stdio.h>`, to my knowledge, don't give you control at a low enough level to be absolutely certain your data is written upon return from a call such as `fflush`.

Note that here I'm talking about sudden unexpected power loss.